# Rails 6. Transferring an attached file from the instance of one model to an instance of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a User model and a Spkr model.

User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :tlks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :spkrs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :msgs, dependent: :destroy

  has_one_attached :image

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

  def slug_candidates
    [
      :username,
      [:username, DateTime.now.to_date]
    ]
  end
end
```

Spkr

```
class Spkr < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tlk
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :msgs, dependent: :destroy

  has_one_attached :image
end
```

When my user model has an image attached, when a spkr is made I want it to have the same image attached to it as the user generating the spkr.

I have a SpkrMaker module:

```
module SpkrMaker
  def make_spkr
    spkr = Spkr.create!(
      user: current_user,
      tlk: @tlk,
      name: current_user.username,
      bio: current_user.bio,
    )
    if current_user.image.present?
      ActiveStorage::Attachment.create(
        name: 'image',
        record_type: 'Spkr',
        record_id: spkr.id,
        blob_id: current_user.image.id
      )
    end
  end
end
```

This is called during the flow, when it is called my server logs state:

```
    Started POST "/tlks" for ::1 at 2020-01-11 10:39:41 +0000
Processing by TlksController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"1NJc0ZSwo8hL1JHw5karkWNxoWRzHPNx/xecaAQHdN+EdsG/o+yZwdxZXLZLPVbkgiPiZZX6PpaF38VX5etTAw==", "tlk"=>{"title"=>"goooolan"}, "commit"=>"Create Tlk"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 23], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/tlks_controller.rb:34:in `create'
  Tlk Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "tlks" WHERE "tlks"."id" IS NOT NULL AND "tlks"."slug" = ? LIMIT ?  [["slug", "goooolan"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/tlks_controller.rb:34:in `create'
  Tlk Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "tlks" ("user_id", "title", "created_at", "updated_at", "slug", "invite_code") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 23], ["title", "goooolan"], ["created_at", "2020-01-11 10:39:41.866979"], ["updated_at", "2020-01-11 10:39:41.866979"], ["slug", "goooolan"], ["invite_code", 469667]]
  ↳ app/controllers/tlks_controller.rb:34:in `create'
   (0.9ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/tlks_controller.rb:34:in `create'
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ lib/spkr_maker.rb:3:in `make_spkr'
  Spkr Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "spkrs" ("tlk_id", "user_id", "name", "bio", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["tlk_id", 135], ["user_id", 23], ["name", "test"], ["bio", "info about me"], ["created_at", "2020-01-11 10:39:41.871219"], ["updated_at", "2020-01-11 10:39:41.871219"]]
  ↳ lib/spkr_maker.rb:3:in `make_spkr'
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ lib/spkr_maker.rb:3:in `make_spkr'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 23], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ lib/spkr_maker.rb:9:in `make_spkr'
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ lib/spkr_maker.rb:10:in `make_spkr'
  Spkr Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "spkrs".* FROM "spkrs" WHERE "spkrs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 104], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ lib/spkr_maker.rb:10:in `make_spkr'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 51], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ lib/spkr_maker.rb:10:in `make_spkr'
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ lib/spkr_maker.rb:10:in `make_spkr'
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 3.7ms | Allocations: 14233)



ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Blob must exist):

lib/spkr_maker.rb:10:in `make_spkr'
app/controllers/tlks_controller.rb:36:in `create
```

When I run User.last.image in the rails console, I get the following:

```
irb(main):002:0> User.last.image
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007f88a21cda90 @name="image", @record=#<User id: 23, email: "j@test.com", username: "test", bio: "info about me", name: nil, created_at: "2020-01-11 01:56:22", updated_at: "2020-01-11 01:56:48", slug: "test">>
irb(main):003:0>
```

I do not know what the problem is, and am not good enough at understanding the server logs to work out what is going wrong.

A Spkr is made during the process, so everything above line 10 is working in the SpkrMaker module (ActiveStorage::Attachment.create( = line 10).

OK Further information as of this morning...(11/01/2020)

```
irb(main):010:0> User.last.image.id
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 23], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> 51
```

But

```
    irb(main):011:0> ActiveStorage::Blob.last.id
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" ORDER BY "active_storage_blobs"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> 49
```

I don't know why there is this difference.

Comment: Is it necessary for you the make an extra image record since you can access the same image which is uploaded and attached to user model from `Spkr`.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point! I'd still be interested to know how to resolve it though. @SantoshAryal

Comment: Well, can you please share the log of the complete action.

Comment: You mean before the make_spkr function starts running?

Comment: yes,  please paste the log.

Comment: ok, that is in the question now @SantoshAryal

Comment: I think there is some validations issue. Please run the module with `ActiveStorage::Attachment.create!()` and see the log. It will provide you the information why the record has not been added.

Comment: @SantoshAryal I have updated the question again, there is now more information and it says that blob does not exist. Below the logs, I have put what happens when I run User.last.image, which seems to show a blog present?

Comment: As the errors says, Blobs must exist and in your mode there is `has_one_attached :image`. It means you have to upload the image. So, try removing the has_on_attached form model Spkr.

Comment: Will I need to add a column for image in my db? And if I want people to ALSO be able to upload an image for the Spkr model?

Comment: The more I think about it the more I feel like I've overcomplicated things, and I could just have the user have one image and leave it at that.

Comment: That is the good point. Carry on!

Comment: Kind of a follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694064/how-much-should-i-avoid-computations-in-my-views @SantoshAryal + thank you for your help so far

Answer (score 1):

While attaching the image to Spkr you are tagging active storage attachment id of current_user instead of blob_id instead of blob id I have update the code.

```
module SpkrMaker
  def make_spkr
    spkr = Spkr.create!(
      user: current_user,
      tlk: @tlk,
      name: current_user.username,
      bio: current_user.bio,
    )
    if current_user.image.present?
      ActiveStorage::Attachment.create(
        name: 'image',
        record_type: 'Spkr',
        record_id: spkr.id,
        blob_id: current_user.image.blob_id
      )
    end
  end
end
```

It should work now.